# Assigning file path on worker's host while using doParallel in R

Tags: r, doparallel

I am working on a single machine with 8 cores. I want to log the stdout and stderr in a log file using outfile option in makeCluster

```
cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1,      
                 outfile = "log.txt")
```

The above code saves the log file in the working directory. I was wondering how to change the filepath for the outfile to save in any given path. E.g.:

```
cl = makeCluster(detectCores() - 1,     
                 outfile = "\\\\logfolder\\log.txt")
```

When I specified a filepath, I did not get any log file (neither in working directory nor in specified path).
The documentation state that I need to change the file path on the worker's host.

*outfile :
Where to direct the stdout and stderr connection output from the workers. "" indicates no redirection (which may only be useful for workers on the local machine). Defaults to /dev/null (nul: on Windows). The other possibility is a file path on the worker's host. Files will be opened in append mode, as all workers log to the same file.*

Honestly, I am not very good with parallel computing terminology and was wondering if you could help me with changing the file path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to produce 10 separate files in a dummy path - `C:/temp/temp/` based on `i` . You could try a similar approach.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)

parallel_sink <- function(out) {
    O <- file(out, "w")
    sink(O)
    return(O)
}

clusterExport(cl, c("parallel_sink"))

parLapply(
    cl, 
    1:10, 
    function(i) {
        out <- paste0("C:/temp/temp/", i, ".txt")
        worker_out <- parallel_sink(out)
        write(paste0("prints to stdout - ", i), stdout())
        close(worker_out)   
    }
)
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks! This does help generate log files in specified folder but creates a separate file for each iteration (as intended). In my case, it is undesirable as I will be running a loop over 1000 cases. I did try to change the 'out' such that it produces only one file but then the file does not get appended. I might be able to use it if I can get all the output in a single log file.